What is starting a particular service
I am running AlmaLinux 9, and I have a service (called it "X").  I want to figure out what is starting service X (since it is disabled).
Is there a command that will show which other service will start X (as a dependency, or other)?

systemd-analyze seems to be what you're looking after. You'll need to install graphviz to get the graph renderer dot, whose input format systemd-analyze dot generates. (this doesn't have to happen on the same machine. For simplicity, let's do it on the same machine.)
systemd-analyze dot --require > graph.dot
grep -v 'color="red"' | dot -Tsvg Gsplines=line > graph_embedding.svg
firefox graph_embedding.svg # or some other SVG viewer

(here, we suppress the "conflicts with" red edges, and make dot use straight lines when connecting nodes; the splines it uses by default make nearly every larger graph embedding ambiguous to read; it's not clear to me what the authors were thinking there.)
This might be a bit much information in one picture. I'd recommend you whack together a quick script to extract the subtree of reverse dependencies starting from your node of interest, but alas, this is a one-off problem (hopefully), so open graph.dot in your favourite text editor. look for occurrences of ->"X.service", note what is left of the ->, then you either understand what requires X already, or you figure out what starts that service by searching for that as right-side of ->.

This is a headless machine (no GUI), so installing 'dot' brings a whole lot of packages...too much.  Is there a text only version of this same command?

you could just copy the graph.dot file to your desktop machine; you'll want to look at the picture generated from it afterwards, anyways.. Graphviz, however, doesn't do any graphical output of its own – it's a pure command line programm.
